# Algorithm to resolve dependencies and build tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, generic-programming

Google search did not yield any ideas or solutions neither did SO search.( One post existed with same title but different motive).

#### Are there well known algorithms, patterns to resolve dependencies and build a hierarchy of objects.

1. It must be able to build a dependency output tree
2. Handle Circular dependencies

note: I can build one referring to  exiting products build with to do this but knowing what is going to happen, how it should happen I will finish it sooner than other solutions.

Scope of this algorithm would be java script dependency manager, Family tree builder and many more things that may build tree or hierarchy structure from specification. For example taking javascript dependency manager here is how the algorithm would work.

```
Script a dependends

 1. script b 
 2. script c.
```

and

```
Script b depends

 1. Script x 
 2. Script y
```

and

```
Script x depends

1. Script J
```

so here is the order of loading the scripts

```
Script j

  Script a

  Script x, Script y

          Script b
```

Comment: Dependencies are not necessarily a hierarchy or tree structure. They are better defined as a graph. If you search for graph algorithms (both building, then checking if they are acyclic etc) your questions will bear fruit.

Comment: Why not using make, nant, or MSBuild to do this for you?

Comment: @yamen will certainly do that.

Comment: @AlG the algorithm needs to be used in server side control (at runtime)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for **topological sorting**. You will find lots of information about this on the internet.

Comment: topological sorting !! that reminds me of algorithm classes in college Now where did it put that book ahhmm maan..

Comment: Who knew your CS classes would ever be useful? ;-) Amazing.